# Possible to synchronize individual HSL adjustments on Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing

I would like to sync only the Green Saturation between images, or just the Blue Luminance. Is it possible to synchronize individual HSL adjustments on Lightroom, either natively or through a plugin that would allow that fine grained sync?

Answer (score 2):

There's no native way that I'm aware of to do this type of syncing retroactively (i.e. via the *Sync Settings* dialog). It is, however, possible to Auto-Sync or batch apply adjustments to accomplish the same thing. These kinds of adjustments can potentially fall into two categories: absolute and relative.

**Absolute Adjustments**

For absolute adjustments (i.e., you want every photo to have the same numerical value for that particular adjustment slider):

1. Select all of the photos that you want to batch-adjust.
2. Go to the Develop pane.
3. **Auto Sync will only sync *changed* values**. If your primary selected image already has the adjustment that you wish to sync, either select one that doesn't, or enter a dummy value. (If you forget the original value, you can just look at the history panel on the left).
4. Turn on Auto Sync.
5. Type in the adjustment that you wish to sync. The previews often will not update immediately, but your adjustment will have been synced to all of the selected photos.

**Relative Adjustments**

For relative adjustments (i.e., you have already adjusted some photos manually, but now want to apply a constant offset to a setting), there's no way that I'm aware of other than hooking into the API. I have an install of [*VSCO Keys*](https://vsco.github.io/keys/) (which has been freeware for quite some time) that does this. You just select the photos that you want to batch-adjust, then hit the corresponding adjustment hotkey while *Keys* is activated. This is generally not what you want because it's easy to produce inconsistent results that are annoying to undo, but I still do use this a fair bit for bulk offsetting white balance adjustments across a few dozen photos at once. Some caveats on this:

- If you have a lot (20+) of images selected, it will lock up Lightroom for up to several minutes. In the worst case, this can lead to crashes and catalog corruption. I would strongly advise making a catalog backup immediately before doing this method on any kind of a wide scale.
- Lightroom treats each adjusted image in a batch as a separate change when using Keys, so this will quickly saturate the history cache. Read: ***CTRL+Z will not save you.*** This is yet another reason to work in manageable batches. If you mess up on a larger selection, you need to apply the opposite correction via *VSCO Keys*, because CTRL+Z will not undo sufficient steps to revert all the photos, and there's no Lightroom command for "step back a single step in the develop history" that can be auto-synced as far as I'm aware (though there very well may be a *VSCO Keys* binding available for that). You can of course go through and manually edit the history of each photo, but that rapidly becomes unscalable. This is yet another reason to have an up-to-date catalog backup prior to doing this on a large scale.

You can also likely accomplish relative adjustment sync via other LR plugins, but I'm not aware of any free ones that do this particular operation via a dialog. Here is at least [one paid option that I haven't tried](https://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lightroomstatistics/relativeadjustments/). You can also accomplish these API hooks via *[MIDI2LR](https://rsjaffe.github.io/MIDI2LR/)*, which is more complex than *VSCO Keys*, but is better supported these days.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store [the development settings in XMP files](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/help/metadata-basics-actions.html):

> 1. Choose Edit > Catalog Settings (Windows) or Lightroom Classic > Catalog Settings (Mac OS).
> 2. Click the Metadata tab, and then do ... the following:
>
>    - To write adjustments and settings metadata to XMP, select Automatically Write Changes Into XMP.

...then use an advanced text editor (Notepad++, Sublime Text, Visual Studio Code, etc...) to "find in files" and batch replace the value in the XMP files. The field will look like this:

```
<crs:GreenSaturation>0</crs:GreenSaturation>
```

You simply need to do a find & replace to change that 0 value to the value of your choice.

Finally let Lightroom read the settings from the XMP files by selecting the photos, for which you changed the saturation value, in the Library panel and then going to **Metadata > Read Metadata from File**.